# Write HOC as Decorator in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, high-order-component

I am trying to create a decorator which takes an argument from React. Context provider, If I want to create HOC it is easy:

```
interface DashboardProps {
   user: User;
}

class Dashboard extends React.Component<DashboardProps> {
  render() {
     return (<span>{this.props.user.name}</span>);
  }
}

function withUser(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <UserContext.Consumer>
         {user => <WrappedComponent user={user} {...this.props}>}
        </UserContext.Consumer>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default withUser(Dashboard);
```

But I am not sure how to write it like a decorator:

```
@withUser
class Dashboard ...
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise using a decorator.  According to the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators), TypeScript will assume the decorated class has the same members as the original, which isn't true for a typical higher-order component.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen so how is implemented `withRoute`' or `inject` in mobx?

Comment: I don't know that one.  Others feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 1):

The type of class decorator in typescript looks like this:

```js
declare type ClassDecorator = <TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction) => TFunction | void;
```

Which means a class decorator function must return a same typed component, or nothing.

```js
function withUser(WrappedComponent): void {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <UserContext.Consumer>
         {user => <WrappedComponent user={user} {...this.props}>}
        </UserContext.Consumer>
      );
    }
  } as unknown as void;
}
```